# REQUEST_DENIED using valid key and sample query from documentation

Tags: google-places-api

All my requests are denied. My troubleshooting has reached the point of running the sample query from the Places API documentation, like so:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=mykey

...with 'mykey' replaced by my recently-generated browser key from API console. Referers for my simple API access key is set to * to allow all. API console shows no known issues with my Places API use, which is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I should have left 'referers' blank, instead of *